# In the new Yahoo! Mail interface (basic version), how do I 'select all' messages currently shown?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I was recently [forced to switch to the "new" Yahoo! Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5TdW.png) from the Yahoo! Mail Classic interface, which I used for a long time. ([I chose the "basic" version of the "new" interface, not the "Full featured" version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5TdW.png))

I can't seem to find where the 'select all' function is (so I can mass-delete, mass-set as read, etc).

Here's a screenshot of the part of the inbox:

[image]

I can only choose to select each individual email. Anyone know how do I 'select all' messages currently shown?

Answer (score 1):

As lame as it may sound, I don't think there is a "Select all" feature in Basic.